# Erasing from a std::set or std::map of custom type need `operator==`?

Tags: c++, set

When I erase from `std::set` or `std::map` for a custom type, say, `info`, if I use (3) from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/erase, it seems I would need to define an `operator==` for `info`.

However, if I have the iterator pointing to the object that I want to delete, then I believe I don't need the `operator==` and can use (2) from the link. But the following code seems to compile, so I am confused

```
struct info
{
  info(int i, int j, int k) : i{i}, j{j}, k{k} {}
  int i;
  int j;
  int k;

  // bool operator==(const info&rhs)
  // {
  //   return i == rhs.i && j == rhs.j && k == rhs.k;
  // }
};

struct comparer_t
{
  bool operator()(const info &lhs, const info &rhs) const
  {
    if(lhs.i == rhs.i)
    {
      if(lhs.j == rhs.j)
      {
        return lhs.k < rhs.k;
      }

      return lhs.j < rhs.j;
    }

    return lhs.i < rhs.i;
  }
};

int main()
{
  std::set<info, comparer_t> s;
  s.emplace(1,5,6);
  s.erase(info(1,5,6));
  cout << s.size() << endl;
  // cout << (info(1,5,6) == info(1,5,6)) << endl;
}
```

This prints that the size of `s` is `0`. How does the `erase` function know that the key that was inserted using the `emplace` is the same as the one we're searching for without an `operator==`?

Comment: The "comparer" function isn't really to compare elements, it's for *ordering* of the keys in the set. As for why it can be used instead of `==`, it's because the [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings) requirement means that it can be used for equality as well (if `a < b` and `b < a` are both false, then it follows that `a == b`).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Wait. The comparer function is what's leading to the issue in my question?

Comment: @user5965026 your `comparer_t` determines which item gets erased, yes.

Comment: You might take a look at [std::tie](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) for writing comparisons. IMO it's much cleaner and much harder to accidentally get wrong.

Answer (score 6):

> it seems I would need to define an operator== for custom_class.

Your interpretation is not correct. There's no requirement to implement operator==.

> How does the erase function know that the key that was inserted using the emplace is the same as the one we're searching for without an operator==?

Same way as all comparisons of the set know the order: It uses the comparison function that was provided (which is `std::less` by default, `comparer_t` in your example). The objects are considered equivalent if neither compares less than the other.

P.S. In C++20, I recommend following:

```
struct info
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;

    auto operator<=>(const info&) const = default;
};

int main()
{
    std::set<info> s;
    s.emplace(1,5,6);
    s.erase({1,5,6});
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`std::set` and `std::map` do not need an `operator==` to function.  The comparator for `set`/`map` is required to provide [strict weak orderding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings) which allows them to determine equality just using the supplied comparator.

Lets assume the comparator is using a less than relation like yours does. That means `cmp(a, b)` will be `true` if `a` is less than `b`.  Knowing that, then if `cmp(a, b)` is `false`, meaning `a` is not less then `b`, and if `cmp(b, a)` is also `false`, meaning `b` is not less then `a`, then both `a` and `b` must be equal.